# Check on distribution of $X-Y$ and $W_s - W_t$ for a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expected-value, solution-verification, moment-generating-functions

if $X,Y$ are two independent normal random variables, we know that $$X+Y$$ is still $N(u_x+u_y, \sigma^2_x + \sigma^2_y)$, and that's fine. (I proved it via characteristic function)

> Now I want to find the distribution of $X-Y$.

By independence, and looking at the generating function:

$$E[e^{z(X-Y)}]= E[e^{zX} e^{zY}] = E[e^{zX}] E[e^{-zY}] = e^{z(u_x - u_y)} \cdot e^{\frac{z^2}{2} (\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)}$$

and since this is the moment generating function of a $N(u_x - u_y, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)$  I conclude that $$X-Y$$ is distributed as $N(u_x - u_y, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)$

**Is my argument okay?**

Comment: Yes, it seems OK.

Comment: Thanks, I just update my question, please give a look if you can

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is fine.

You could also derive it from the fact you already know about the distribution of $X+Y$: just write $X-Y$ as $X+(-Y)$, and note that $X, -Y$ are independent normal random variables, where $-Y$ has mean $-u_y$ and variance $\sigma_y^2$

Comment: thanks! If you want, I wrote a striclty related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506775/distribution-of-w-s-w-t-st-for-a-brownian-motion  @NateEldredge