# Distribution of $W_s-W_t$, $s<t$ for a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)_t$ a Brownian motion. We know that for $0<s <t$ we have $$W_{t} - W_s$$ is $N(0, t-s)$.

But I've al seen that $W_s - W_t$ is distributed again as $N(0,t-s)$. Why?

Is this because for a normal random variable $X$, $-X$ has the same distribution (since the density function is symmetric)? SO I have that $-(W_t-W_s)$ is distributed ad $W_t - W_s$

Or am I still missing something?

---

Comment: I can't see anything written after "Another question, stricly related is:". The answer to your first question is exactly what you say about symmetry of normal random variables.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! The last line of the question of course doesn't mean anything!